# Angular2: Live reload taking ~10sec even with some minor changes

Tags: typescript, angular, livereload

OS: Mac OS X

I am using ng-cli to Bootstrap the project. I have not changed much to the auto generated files.

Following is the generated npm config file.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-world-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.1.8",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.19",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
    "karma": "^0.13.15",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^0.5.5",
    "tslint": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^0.8.1"
  }
}
```

[image]

I don't know why few bytes of files are taking ~1 sec to load.
I googled but didn't find any much relevant to this.
Please help.

Edit: 
In Safari browser It is loading much faster but in Firefox and Chrome it is very slow.

Comment: What wrong with the question. Can you explain the reason for down vote?

Comment: i don't know who down voted it, but the question might be to vague or broad. you need to show some code of what you are doing and not just a screenshot; something that we can copy and try to reproduce so we can help you.

Comment: I have attached the Network Log. It is just a hello world Angular 2 app generated using **ng-cli**

Comment: I assume this is because the question doesn't contain any information that allows to reproduce the issue. There is no project configuration info and no information about the computer or OS your are using. There is nothing left for anyone to do but guessing. The screenshot should be included in the question directly instead of linking to an external resource. When this link becomes broken this question becomes completely worthless for future visitors that find it because of similar problems.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post screenshot directly. So, I can only share link.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @GünterZöchbauer. I've attached the OS and package.json file.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer for attaching the screenshot.

Comment: no reason to down vote this, this is actually a good question